# ssh connection refused, port listening, process running, IP address not banned

Tags: networking, ssh, firewall, git

```
$ git pull
ssh: connect to host HOSTNAME port 22: Connection refused
```

This only happens when the client is connected to one specific wireless network.  If I connect from a wired connection (even in the same room!) or from any other wireless network (even with the same laptop!), ssh connects fine.

Things I've tried/checked based on other forum posts I've read:

- Verified ssh is installed and running on both client and server
- Verified ssh port is open and listening
- Verified IP address is not banned by fail2ban or ufw (which are running on the server).
- Verified IP address is not blocked in /etc/hosts.deny

The IP address had been banned in the past so that seemed the most likely candidate, but now the IP address is definitely not banned (I checked multiple times over multiple days). In fact, the failed attempt to connect does not even show up in logs.  I checked ufw.log, fail2ban.log, or auth.log

As I said above, I can ssh (for git pull and directly ssh) to this same server from other client machines, or using the same client if I connect it to a different network.  So it seems not to be a general configuration problem with ssh or git or fail2ban but rather something with this specific network.

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like a Firewall related issue to me. Could try installing nc and doing tests from wired versus wireless:
nc -zv 127.0.0.1 22

Comment: Is this a VPS or localhost?  If this is a remote VPS, then you probably need to see if there's a firewall at play at the provider level.